# Checking uri segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I want to check if uri segment($sef) is in array, before sending id to database. 
And I want to ask which solution is better, or if is there something better.

Here are examples of how I tried to search the array

**1)**

```
  if(array_search($sef, array_column($array,'sef'))) {
    //find id and send it to DB
  } else {
    //wrong sef
  }
```

**2)**

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if( in_array($sef, $v)) {
       return $v['id']; break;  
       } else {
       //wrong sef
       } 
   }
```

this is example of array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sef] =>some-sef1
            [id] => 39
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sef] => some-sef2
            [id] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sef] => some-sef3
            [id] => 38
        )
```

Thanks for answers!

Comment: I find the first one is easiest to follow, so how do you define best?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on situation. For small size array, both of them will almost take same time.

1) If it's a small array, you can do it using in_array.

2) If it's a large array, You should use first one. Because a foreach will take more time to execute than array_search.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are almost the same, so it's a preference choice. 
There are some tweaks possible though. First:

```
$sef_ids = array_column($array, 'id', 'sef');
if (isset($sef_ids[$sef])) { $id = $sef_ids[$sef]; ... }
```

Second:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['sef'] === $sef) { $id = $v['id']; ... }
}
```

Now first one looks faster (didn't check), but it's still micro optimization unless you work with large arrays. I would aim for having `$sef_ids` data structure to work with from the beginning then.